# How can I get Airflow on Linux run a VBS script that is automatically downloading SAP data?

Tags: vbscript, winrm, dcom, sap, airflow

I have an Airflow installed on CentOS and I am able to run scripts/commando's on my Windows 10 machine.

However, I have a VBS script that starts Excel and SAP Logon and then automatically logins, fills in some fields and download a file. When I run this on the Windows machine via cmd, PowerShell or scheduler it works fine.

However, when I run this via Airflow it doesn't work. Initially it didn't start the Excel and SAP instance. I got this working by changing DCOM configurations. What is remaining is that it automatically clicks the field and fill in the data and then download the file.

I assume I might have to change some DCOM settings to enable controlling screens and mouse movement, but I have no idea.

I would really appreciate your thoughts and potential solutions.